# Error:layout bounds on right border must start at edge

Tags: android, aapt, android-studio-3.0

My project works fine yesterday; but when I Updated Android studio to 3.0 today and accordingly AAPT2 is enables by default. I have the following error:

```
Error:layout bounds on right border must start at edge.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevDebugResources'.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

I opened log file but can not find a clue. when I google `Error:layout bounds on right border must start at edge` questions about 9-patches in come in results. I have about 10 9-patches in my project too. but I am not sure what is the problem. I know I can disable Aapt2 but I want to resolve problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check which one of them is bad by running "gradlew --info assembleDebug" in the terminal. In my case I removed the red border from one of them. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh thanks Yes there was a red border there. `Exception while processing job : QueuedJob{
title=Compiling bubble1.9.png` shows me **bubble1.9.png** had a problem! Thank you.

Comment: can you explain me about that red boarder?

Comment: Don't recall what the red border was for, can't find any official doc also now. It was an old nine patch that had black and red border on the right side. I simply removed it, perhaps now that red border is no longer necessary; haven't tested the effect yet :) Funny thing is I have multiple nine patches with red border, but with no problem.

Comment: Do you know any resource where all this gradle commands are listed?

Comment: It is not a command, just told the gradle to run one of tasks that is normally ran automatically by studio with info log level. Take look at the pic to find the rest of them https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOxf5.png

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I just removed red dots from all 9.png images and it compiled. Not yet sure if any run-time nightmares am going to face as result of this.What a pathetic experience of upgrading Android Studio. It wasted my hours :(

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem after updating to 3.0. Added this line in the "gradle.properties" file of my project.

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes it works. but as I saved I don't wand to disable Aapt2, I want to solve the problem.

Comment: Now `android.enableAapt2` is deprecated.

Comment: This is **not** correct solution. Answer by crios works. Remove red dots from 9.png images.